# ActiveRecord#sanitize_sql_array method changes integer to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I recently upgraded the rails version of my application from 6.1 to 7. After upgrading I found that `sanitize_sql_array` is now changing the integer values to string.

Below are the attributes that I am passing to the method:

```
updates = ["`bed_count` = `bed_count` + ?", "`operating_room_count` = `operating_room_count` + ?", "`updated_at` = ?"]
values = [3.14159, 1, "2022-09-17 18:15:05"]
```

Now when the run the method I get the following output:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [updates.join(','), *values])
=> "`bed_count` = `bed_count` + '3.14159',`operating_room_count` = `operating_room_count` + '1',`updated_at` = '2022-09-17 18:33:44'"
```

Notice that the 3.14159 and 1 is now changed to string even though I provided integer values.

When I ran the same code in Rails 6.1, I got the following output:

```
"`bed_count` = `bed_count` + 3.14159,`operating_room_count` = `operating_room_count` + 1,`updated_at` = '2022-09-17 18:33:44'"
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this ?

Comment: I've tried on 7.0.3.1 and they are numeric. BTW, why do you use `send`? It's public method, you can `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array([updates.join(','), *values])`

Comment: @mechnicov I again tried with `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_array([updates.join(','), *values])` but still got the same output with string instead of numeric.
"`bed_count` = `bed_count` + '3.14159',`operating_room_count` = `operating_room_count` + '1',`updated_at` = '2022-09-17 18:15:05'"

Comment: What active_record version do you have?

Comment: @mechnicov currently on 7.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42440?

> The MySQL adapter now cast numbers and booleans bind parameters to string for safety reasons.

I guess they're working on a fix for your problem here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45379

Think the best workaround right now is to cast the strings to integer/decimals in the SQL like this:

```
...bed_count` + CAST(? as UNSIGNED)
# or 
CAST(? as DECIMAL)
```